# Why is my Edit WCF Configuration option missing?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I created WCF RIA services. It added app.config by default. But there is no option of Edit WCF Configuration that appears when you create simple WCF services. What am i missing? How do i get that GUI tool? Do i have to write all that xml and remember for the next time when i use it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be a link in the main Tools menu to the editor, or alternatively [run it externally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) and open your app.config from it's menu.

Comment: thanks, it appeared in my menu, but when i clicked it said "SDK not installed correctly". but with your method works. hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 23):

This is a known bug - at times, you have to select it from the `Tools` menu once and close it again right away, before it becomes available as a right-click context-menu option on your `app.config` file.

I would have hoped this would have been fixed in Visual Studio 2010 - but it's still there...

Comment: I didn't get it back but still +1 ;)

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to tools
3. Click on Edit WCF Service Configuration

Answer (score 4):

Choose Tools --> Edit WCF Service Configuration Editor

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Visual Studio command prompt & type ***SvcConfigEditor***

OR

2)Navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin\SvcConfigEditor.exe

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022, I could not locate a way to Edit Wcf configuration. Maybe I need to install more components of VS 2022 ? Anyways, I used Tools->External Tools menu item in VS 2022 to define a way to open the Wcf configuration myself.

Then hit start menu and search for 'cmd' or 'Developer command prompt' and choose the version suitable for you (e.g. 2022). Now enter :

```
svcconfigeditor
```

This opens a new window with svcconfigeditor and must succeed, or else you do not have installed Svc config editor anyways.. The tool which 'Edit wcf configuration' will open.

Next type this command :

```
where svcconfigeditor
```

This should show you the path to the executable on your system.

[Locating svcconfigeditor executable on your Windows system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEVfR.png)

Go back again to Tools->Exernal Tools and hit 'Add' button

Give these values (example, last two values must be set):

Title: 'Edit Wcf configuration'
Command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\SvcConfigEditor.exe
Arguments:
$(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt)
Initial dir:
$(ItemDir)

[External Tools - creating a edit wcf configuration tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQCrm.png)
Now - switch back to Solution explorer with the web.config file containing your web.config file.
Select the web.config file and choose :
Tools=>Edit Wcf configuration

[Editing wcf configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N94YI.png)

Please note that I suspect Edit WCF configuration tools are better with older VS versions as WCF is getting replaced with