# No 'WCF Service Configuration Editor' in the tools menu

Tags: wcf

I downloaded VS Web Developer 2010 Express and successfully made a WCF service using the default options (works fine so no issues compiling and running it).

However, now I want to edit the WCF config but in the tools menu the WCF editor link is missing (It is not in the menu nor in the context menu).

Is there a way to make this option appear by re-registering or something (I know I can launch it manually but it worries me it is not in the menu)?

Comment: See [my response here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089507/why-is-my-edit-wcf-configuration-option-missing/4089808#4089808) - it's a known bug - with a workaround.

Comment: I already knew about that bug. The problem is I don't even have the option in the main menu to open the editor!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Windows SDK and then it should be available here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\
The name is SvcConfigEditor.exe

Comment: I know it is indeed possible to run from that path, but the fact that it is not visible in the IDE makes me worry other stuff isn't correctly configured as well.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it? Otherwise you could add it as an external source when everything else runs corretly.